# do while loop is looping when I don't want it to

Tags: java, loops, do-while

I have a do while loop, and it is not working. As you can see in my code it is supposed to loop if the variable "choice" is not equal to p or n. even if I make choice equal p or n it loops at least once. Do I have bad placement or something?

```
    do{
        System.out.println("Enter the name of the contact you would like to update");
        name = sc.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Would you like to update their name(press n) or phone"
                + "number(press p)?");
        choice = sc.nextLine();
        if(choice.equalsIgnoreCase("n")){
            System.out.println("Enter the new name for the contact");
            String name1 = sc.nextLine();
            SQL.updateName(name, name1);
            c = SQL.searchByName(name1);
            if(c != null)
                System.out.printf("Name: %s\t Phonenumber: %s\n", c.getName(), c.getPhone());
            else
                System.out.println(name+" does not exist");
        }
        else if(choice.equalsIgnoreCase("p")){
            System.out.println("Enter the new number for "+name);
            phone = sc.nextLine();
            SQL.updateNumber(name, phone);
            c = SQL.searchByPhone(phone);
            if(c != null)
                System.out.printf("Name: %s\t Phonenumber: %s\n", c.getName(), c.getPhone());
            else
                System.out.println(name+" does not exist");
        }
        }
        while(choice.equalsIgnoreCase("p") == false || choice.equalsIgnoreCase("n") == false);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your logic is incorrect; any `choice` will always be either not equal to `"p"` or not equal to `"n"`.  You want to loop only if it's not `"p"` *and* it's not `"n"`.  Use `&&`:

```
while(choice.equalsIgnoreCase("p") == false && choice.equalsIgnoreCase("n") == false);
```

Comment: that's true, but OP is using `do-while` and complains that it always executes once. It will even after the change you suggested

Comment: @Lucas `choice` isn't even initialized until it's inside the `do-while` loop.  The loop needs to run at least once.  The complaint here is that the loop _continues_ to loop even if `"p"` or `"n"` is entered.

Comment: I suggest `!choice.equalsIgnoreCase("p")` rather than `choice.equalsIgnoreCase("p") == false`. In the first case, I can easily see that it evaluates to true if choice is not `"p"` or `"P"`, but in the second, I think the opposite until I read the `== false`, then I have to go back and see what is false.